# Configure Apache ssl.conf for Java 7u25 support

Tags: java, apache, ssl

In an attempt to harden my ssl server I have inadvertently broken a third party integration. They need Java 7u25 support in our SSL config and now we apparently do not have it with this config.

ssllabs.com says we have "Java 7u25   Protocol or cipher suite mismatch"

we have configured ssl.conf

```
#   SSL Protocol support:
SSLProtocol  -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
SSLCipherSuite 
 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:
 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:
 AES128-GCM-SHA256:
 AES256-GCM-SHA384:
 AES128-SHA256:
 AES256-SHA256:
 AES:
 !aNULL:
 !eNULL:
 !EXPORT:
 !DES:
 !RC4:
 !MD5:
 !PSK:
 !aECDH:
 !EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:
 !EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:
 !KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

(formatting of cipher suites in ssl.conf is all in one line without spaces; it was changed one per line in this post for readability)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Java 7 needs TLSv1 support which you've disabled. Re-enable it and you might be able to use that AES cipher depending what that corresponds to, but it probably can't use the SHA256 or SHA384 ones (again in default mode).

Best to run your site through ssllabs.com again and then compare the ciphers available to the Java 7 list: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Java&version=7u25

Btw Java 7 **can** support TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 but not by default (see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) and have seen people struggle to get them working.

Comment: Thank you. The vendor uses TLSv1.2 so obviously I will never pass the openssl test. I will post another question to get an answer about the cypher suites since you have properly answered this question.